# find's - cnewer broken on NTFS-3g?

Tags: files, find, timestamps, stat, ntfs-3g

After extracting an archive to the wrong place, I thought I'd erase everything created after it, but `find . -cnewer archive.7z` gave the wrong results.

So I made a controlled test by `touch`ing three files and changing their `ctime` with `mv` so they'd be in the opposite order:

```
$ stat --printf '%n mod: %y chg: %z\n' oldest middle newest 
oldest mod: 21:57:13.935530400 chg: 22:05:48.369608300
middle mod: 21:58:23.939659500 chg: 22:05:09.911614500
newest mod: 21:59:33.943477100 chg: 22:04:55.869205500
```

(Trimmed for legibility)

Now let's test `-newer` and `-cnewer`:

```
$ find . -type f -newer middle 
./newest
```

Okay.

```
$ find . -type f -cnewer middle 
./middle
./newest
./oldest
```

Not okay.

From `fstab` and `mount`:

```
UUID=46A8DB5D20C177B0 /mnt/stuff  ntfs  rw,uid=ariel,fmask=027,dmask=027 0 0
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/stuff type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the `find` manpage's description of `-cnewer`

> -cnewer *file*
>
> File's **status was last changed** more recently than *file* was **modified**.

Emphasis mine.

All of the files were modified before 22:00 and were changed after 22:00, so they were all **changed** after any one of them was **modified**. Thus they are all listed.

So the result seems correct.

Whether that makes `-cnewer` useful or not is a different question!